# What is the purpose of adding a .po file?

Tags: plugins, multi-language, translation

I added the below code to the `function.php` of a **.po** file and finished localization and edited the `webconfig.php` to add Arabic language but nothing happened. I want to know what should happen. Will the site include the new language - in my situation Arabic,  or what?

Now the website is in English and I want to add an Arabic version.

```
<?php load_theme_textdomain('themename', TEMPLATEPATH.'/language'); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, read [**this Codex page**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) about translating WordPress.

You have to create a language file to put into your language directory, do this by following the next steps:

**I assume you want to use *poedit* since you talk about a `.po` file**

1. [download poedit](http://www.poedit.net/download.php)
2. File > new catalog
3. In the first tab, fill in the fields, the most important ones are

   - Language, in your case: **`ar`**
   - Plural Forms, set this to: **`nplurals=2; plural=n == 1 ? 0 : 1;`**
4. In the second tab, set the path to: **`../`** and add path: **`.`**
5. In the last tab, add the following values:

   - `__`
   - `_e`
   - `_n`
   - `_x:2c,1`
   - `_xn`
   - `_ex`
   - `esc_attr__`
   - `esc_attr_e`
   - `esc_attr_x`
   - `esc_html__`
   - `esc_html_e`
   - `esc_html_x`
   - `_n_noop`
   - `_nx_noop`
   - `translate_nooped_plural`
6. Save the catalog in your themes' **languages** directory as: **ar.po**
7. Poedit will search for translations and then show them
8. Translate the strings and save the file.

This `.po` file will contain all your translated strings wich WordPress will use to translate your added code.

To display WordPress itself in your language, download the language files from the Codex page and add them to your wordpress **languages** directory.

Then, in your `wp-config.php`, set the following line:

```
define( 'WPLANG', 'ar' );
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i think you didnt understand my question all what i need to know is that when i done all the steps the words translated from english to arabic but i want to have the two languages for the website not only arabic ... i mean to have a button to translate from arabic to english

Comment: You didn't mentioned that in your question. WordPress does not support a bilingual or multilingual blog out-of-the-box. There are however Plugins developed by the WordPress community which will allow you to create a multilingual blog easily. Take a look at [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress) for more information.

Comment: thaanks alot mike i will check it now but one more question is it better to use that plugins or to make pages for arabic and pages for english and make a button that move you from english page to arabic page

Comment: As you can read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress#How_to_choose_the_right_multilingual_solution), you have to choose a way adapted to the content strategy you have. SEO and experience is a important aspect. I think my choice would be a multisite solution with one multisite for English and another for Arabic content. Your choice to make a button to switch from content page is another solution you could use, and not a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mike regarding the purpose and general how to, I can just suggest that instead of using poedit, you can use a plugin called "[codestyling localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/)" which enables editing the .po files directly from wordpress.

Also, make sure you create the appropriate .mo files, otherwise things won't be loaded.

Comment: thanks oferwald this plugin looks cool but can it make the 2 languages exist by adding a button at the top that transfer from english to arabic

Comment: No, that plugin (codestyling) does not allow you to do that, if you wish to have two languages that you can switch between there are many on the repository, mine (transposh) is one of them.